# vscode: how to debug golang in live-share mode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, delve, vscode-liveshare

When livesharing my code with golang, I could not start debugging mode (i'm using delve)

Here is my launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "debugAdapter": "dlv-dap",
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "./main.go",
            "args": ["server"]
        }
    ]
}
```